# How to translate a sentence that has no particles

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, manga

I'm reading a manga and a man (Shusuke) and woman (Nozomi) are having a conversation. It starts out with them talking about congratulating a mutual friend (Sawada) on getting a job when Shusuke says:

(1)

> あーあいつのぞみちゃん狙いだからな

I believe it says "Ah— That guy (Sawada) is aiming for you, Nozomi-chan." Since there are no particles, I'm just guessing.

Nozomi responds by saying Sawada told her she can make a reservation to the restaurant any time she wants and then says:

(2)

> なんだったかな？**ル**の**つく**お店

Which I've translated to "I wonder..." but I don't understand the rest of the sentence because I don't know what **ル**　means which, in turn, causes me to not know what **つく**　means. I'm guessing **つく**　is a verb because when I look it up on jisho.org, only verbs come up. Jisho.org doesn't turn anything up for **ル／る** either.

So, I guess I actually have 2 questions, but I didn't want to separate them because they flow together for contextual reasons.

1. How to translate the first sentence since there are no particles
2. What does **ルのつく** mean

Comment: I feel it could be ル as in the French "Le". The basic meaning being "A restaurant with 'le' attached to the name", which has a kind of implication of some fancy French place that she's wondering if she can get a reservation at? Could be completely off though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「あー、あいつのぞみちゃん[狙]{ねら}いだからな。」

＝

> 「あー、あいつ**は**のぞみちゃん狙いだからな。」

This sentence means exactly what you guessed it did.

Note that there is no particle "omitted" between 「のぞみちゃん」 and 「狙い」.  「～～狙い」("aiming at ~~") is a very common phrase and it can be treated as one word as far as grammar.

Regarding 「ルのつくお[店]{みせ}」, it means "***the shop/eatery whose name starts with 「ル」***".  「つく」 is indeed a verb and it is written 「付く」 in kanji.  = "***to be attached***", literally.  Here, it means "***to be included (in the spelling), particularly as the first kana***".

「ルのつくお店」 is, of course, a relative clause in which 「の」 means 「が」.  There has been a question about this 「の」 recently.

Comment: So I can use the ”ルの付く” set-up as a general format for "noun that starts with this (or has this) kana?"　(kana) の付く (noun)

Comment: @Rose Yes, 付く can mean both "starts with" and "has". For example, see [数字のつく歌](http://www.8107.net/d_mite/game15.html).